# Boto3 s3 put operation getting "HTTPClientError"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, stringio

I started getting this error when trying to put a test csv to s3:

> HTTPClientError: An HTTP Client raised and unhandled exception:
>   Timeout value connect was Timeout(connect=60, read=60, total=None),
>   but it must be an int, float or None.

It was working fine at first and then just started giving this seemingly out of nowhere. I have the same script sitting on an EC2 server and it works fine from there, but does not work locally

```
import boto3
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from io import StringIO

ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'removed'
ACCESS_SECRET_KEY = 'removed'
region_name = 'us-west-2'

client = boto3.client( service_name = "s3", region_name =region_name ,
                                                aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY_ID, aws_secret_access_key=ACCESS_SECRET_KEY
                                              ) 
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3', aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY_ID,
                               aws_secret_access_key=ACCESS_SECRET_KEY)

dest_bucket = 'mybucket'

df = pd.DataFrame({'Animal': ['Falcon', 'Falcon',
                             'Parrot', 'Parrot'],
                    'Max Speed': [380., 370., 24., 26.]})

csv_buffer = StringIO()
df.to_csv(csv_buffer, index = False)

s3_resource.Object(dest_bucket, 'test.csv').put(Body=csv_buffer.getvalue())
```

Does anybody know what might be causing this? Full traceback

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-23-6e25ea0d6e73>", line 30, in <module>
    s3_resource.Object(dest_bucket, 'ec2-test/' + 'ec2_testLIVe.csv').put(Body=csv_buffer.getvalue())

  File "C:\Users\mkjacks5\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\boto3\resources\factory.py", line 520, in do_action
    response = action(self, *args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\mkjacks5\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\boto3\resources\action.py", line 83, in __call__
    response = getattr(parent.meta.client, operation_name)(**params)

  File "C:\Users\mkjacks5\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 357, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\mkjacks5\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 648, in _make_api_call
    operation_model, request_dict, request_context)

  File "C:\Users\mkjacks5\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 667, in _make_request
    return self._endpoint.make_request(operation_model, request_dict)

  File "C:\Users\mkjacks5\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\endpoint.py", line 102, in make_request
    return self._send_request(request_dict, operation_model)

  File "C:\Users\mkjacks5\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\endpoint.py", line 137, in _send_request
    success_response, exception):

  File "C:\Users\mkjacks5\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\endpoint.py", line 231, in _needs_retry
    caught_exception=caught_exception, request_dict=request_dict)

  File "C:\Users\mkjacks5\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\hooks.py", line 356, in emit
    return self._emitter.emit(aliased_event_name, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\mkjacks5\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\hooks.py", line 228, in emit
    return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\mkjacks5\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\hooks.py", line 211, in _emit
    response = handler(**kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\mkjacks5\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\retryhandler.py", line 183, in __call__
    if self._checker(attempts, response, caught_exception):

  File "C:\Users\mkjacks5\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\retryhandler.py", line 251, in __call__
    caught_exception)

  File "C:\Users\mkjacks5\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\retryhandler.py", line 269, in _should_retry
    return self._checker(attempt_number, response, caught_exception)

  File "C:\Users\mkjacks5\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\retryhandler.py", line 317, in __call__
    caught_exception)

  File "C:\Users\mkjacks5\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\retryhandler.py", line 223, in __call__
    attempt_number, caught_exception)

  File "C:\Users\mkjacks5\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\retryhandler.py", line 359, in _check_caught_exception
    raise caught_exception

  File "C:\Users\mkjacks5\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\endpoint.py", line 200, in _do_get_response
    http_response = self._send(request)

  File "C:\Users\mkjacks5\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\endpoint.py", line 244, in _send
    return self.http_session.send(request)

  File "C:\Users\mkjacks5\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\httpsession.py", line 298, in send
    raise HTTPClientError(error=e)
```

Windows machine, python 3. Looks like it is complaining about the connect argument value not being a number, but it says 60? Couldn't find anything about this when googling, appreciate any help